# Cutting a row of a table (selecting the row only where the cursor is placed) and pasting the row into another table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to cut a row from one table in MS word using vba and paste it into the last row of another table in the same document.

This is what I have so far and it stops at the highlighted section.

```
    Sub Select_Paste_1()
'
' Select_Paste_1 Macro
'
'
Dim oTable As Table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oCurrentRow As Row

Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set oCurrentRow = oTable.Rows(Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex)

oCurrentRow.Select
With Selection
Selection.Cut
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Add
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Count).Range.Paste
End With
End Sub
```

For additional context: the end desired result is to cut the row from the first table in the document where the user has their cursor placed, and paste to the END of the second table of the document WITH the formatting of that second table. Ideally, the user would not have to select the row when the macro runs, rather, they would simply have their cursor in the row that they wish to "approve" and move to the bottom of the second table. Additionally, I'm hoping to attach this to a button in the customized toolbar.

Comment: forgot to add - where it highlights is: ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Count).Range.Paste

Comment: Run time error 4605 "This command is not available."

Comment: As long as I have a row in the first table selected (highlighted), your code works with no issues for me.

Comment: The error message still appears when I run the code. For additional context: the end desired result is to cut the row row from the first table in the document where the user has their cursor placed, and paste to the END of the second table of the document WITH the formatting of that second table. Ideally, the user would not have to select the row when the macro runs, rather, they would simply have their cursor in the row that they wish to "approve" and move to the bottom of the second table. Additionally, I'm hoping to attach this to a button in the customized toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Select_Paste_1()
    '
    ' Select_Paste_1 Macro
    '
    '
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oCell As Cell
    Dim oCurrentRow As Row

    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set oCurrentRow = oTable.Rows(Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex)
    oCurrentRow.Select
    Selection.Cut
    
    Dim newLastRow As Row
    Set newLastRow = ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows.Add
    newLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
End Sub
```